# How do I loop a function in c#?

Tags: c#, function, procedures

I have been given this question, in my computer science class, and I cannot figure out how to answer it. 
Question:

•Create a procedure called tossCoins with one integer parameter - numTosses

•Inside your tossCoins procedure, call your tossCoin function from challenge #5 
numTosses times. So for example if we enter tossCoins(50), the tossCoin function will be called 50 times.

•Your tossCoins procedures should then print out the number of times that the coin landed on heads and the number of times the coin landed on tails

•Extend your main program, so that the user can choose how many times to toss the coin

I have already created the tossCoin function, but cannot figure out how to run it the amount of times the user asks, or how to create a tally of heads and tails. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine(tossCoin(rnd));

        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        int numTosses = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string tossCoin(Random rnd)
    {
        int num = rnd.Next(1, 3);

        string heads = "Heads";
        string tails = "Tails";

        if(num == 1)
        {
            return heads;
        }
        else
        {
            return tails;
        }
    }

    static void tossCoins(int numTosses)
    {
        int headsTally = 0;
        int tailsTally = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numTosses; i++)
        {
            string outcome = tossCoin(rnd);
            numTosses--;
            if(outcome == heads)
            {
                headsTally++;
            }
            else
            {
                tailsTally++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, it would be great, as I am trying to learn the different rules of using functions, and procedures. Thanks, Leighton.

Comment: `numTosses--;` this line should be deleted. Your for loop is keeping count for you (hint:  the `i++` part).  `if(outcome == heads)`  this line shouldn't compile.  outcome is a string and `heads` isn't defined in the scope of `tossCoins`.  Lastly, you should think about what your `tossCoins` should return, probably should be something (not void)

Comment: Thanks, this has really helped. I am having a problem though. in my for loop, when I call the function tossCoin(rnd), for some reason, the rnd is underlined, and produces an error, "The name "rnd" does not exist in current context". Why am I getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: Because your random variable is not in scope.  It is declared in your main function, not tossCoins.  Perhaps look into either passing the random to your tossCoins function or look into global variables :)

Answer (score -1):

A couple things, first it looks like you've almost got it. You just need to call your `tossCoins()` function in your main method. Second, you don't need to decrement `numTosses` in your for loop, ie. remove the line `numTosses--;`

EDIT: as Tommy said, the statement `outcome == heads` wont compile since `heads` isn't defined. Either replace heads with `"Heads"` or define it earlier in the function. And yea you might want to return/print the result.

Comment: Thanks so much, look at the reply I left Tommy. Cheers.

Comment: @LeightonBlackburn you need to pass `rnd` to `tossCoins(numTosses, rnd);` and change the header of tossCoins to `tossCoins(int numTosses, Random rnd)`

Comment: Cheers man, it worked! The only problem I have, is my teacher asked to only have 1 parameter, not 2, but I believe this isn't possible, right? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wasn't me. my vote doesn't show up publicly yet, though mine will be an upvote.